# How to control the login flow in ADAL AuthenticationContext?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

Using the ADAL library for getting a token for WAAD i would like to know how I can get more control over the login flow.

```
var ac = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + ActiveDirectoryTenantId);
AuthenticationInfo = ac.AcquireToken(
                         resource: "https://management.core.windows.net/",
                         clientId: "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2",
                         redirectUri: new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"));
```

The user is prompted to login. For me it's via Live Id, for my customer's computer it's via an organizational account, and there is no way to switch between them. It seems to be controlled by how/what current sessions the computer might have running already logged into azure.

Can I do anything in the AcquireToken call to control this?
It would be best if I could trigger the normal flow when people log into Azure where they get to select if its a live id or a organizational login.

I have tried this:

```
ac.AcquireToken("https://management.core.windows.net/",
                    "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2",
                    new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"), PromptBehavior.Always,"wtrealm=urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline");
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some magic tricks that seems to give some more control.

```
// ID for site to pass to enable EBD (email-based differentiation)
// This gets passed in the call to get the azure branding on the
// login window. Also adding popup flag to handle overly large login windows.
internal const string EnableEbdMagicCookie = "site_id=501358&display=popup";

private void ClearCookies()
{
    NativeMethods.InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, NativeMethods.INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
}

private static class NativeMethods
{
    internal const int INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION = 42;

    [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer,
        int lpdwBufferLength);
}
```

Comment: This needs to be embedded in an ADAL method... Native clients sometimes need to change logged in users without restarting!