# Can Azure AD ADAL (ios) refresh token be revoked from the client?

Tags: azure, adal

I am trying to use [ADALiOS](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc) in an iOS app. I also want to have a logout button so that, if needed, the user can elect to logout from the app. The best way, I think, would be to revoke the refresh token (the access token is short-lived and can't be revoked), which ideally should also revoke the token and do clean up on the server-side.

I tried Azure AD docs, searched in the source code (and in general searched elsewhere), but couldn't find any mention of refresh token revocation in ADAL.

Can a refresh token be revoked in ADAL? What is the best way to log a user out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. From [`Best Practices for OAuth 2.0 in Azure AD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/azure/dn645536.aspx):

> Refresh tokens do not have specified lifetimes. Typically, the
>   lifetimes of refresh tokens are relatively long. **However, in some
>   cases, refresh tokens expire, are revoked, or lack sufficient
>   privileges for the desired action**. The client application needs to
>   expect and handle errors returned by the token issuance endpoint
>   correctly. When you receive a response with a refresh token error,
>   discard the current refresh token and request a new authorization code
>   or access token. In particular, when using a refresh token in the
>   Authorization Code Grant flow, if you receive a response with the
>   interaction_required or invalid_grant error codes, discard the refresh
>   token and request a new authorization code.

Also I remember Vittorio mentioning in his blog post ([`ADAL 3 didn’t return refresh tokens for ~5 months… and nobody noticed`](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/08/13/adal-3-didnt-return-refresh-tokens-for-5-months-and-nobody-noticed/)) that ADAL 3 doesn't even return refresh tokens. I guess the general recommendation is not to take any dependency on refresh tokens in your application.

Regarding logging out the user, please see this thread: [ADAL: W8.1 app trying to log user out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061948/adal-w8-1-app-trying-to-log-user-out), though this thread is for Windows Phone app.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I am looking for a way to log user out. The best way, I think, would be to revoke the refresh token (the access token is short-lived and can't be revoked), which ideally should also revoke and do clean up on the server-side.

Comment: That was not your question. Can you please describe what you're looking for?

Comment: I have expanded on my question now. Thanks for prompting me to. If I understand it correctly, the reference you have provided above talks about the revocation of refresh tokens from the server (which needs to be handled on the client appropriately). Is there a way to revoke it from the client? Remember, ADAL is an authentication library to be used on the client side.

Comment: Regarding logging out the user, please see if this thread answers your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061948/adal-w8-1-app-trying-to-log-user-out (though it is for Windows Phone app).

Comment: Thanks, Gaurav. That link should work. Please mark that as the answer.

Comment: Awesome! You would need to mark my response as an answer if you think that's the correct answer :). What I could do is mark your question as duplicate to that other question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link Gaurav provided, here is the logout code for ADAL Objective-c, for the sample app provided by Azure AD:

In viewcontroller:

```
- (IBAction)logoutUser:(id)sender
{
    [self.unifiedEndpointClient logoutUser];
}
```

In O365UnifiedEndpointOperations:

```
-(void)logoutUser
{
    AuthenticationManager *authenticationManager = [AuthenticationManager sharedInstance];
    [authenticationManager removeTokenWithResourceId:_resourceID
                                          withTenant:TENANT_STRING];
}
```

In AuthenticationManager:

```
-(void) removeTokenWithResourceId:(NSString *)resourceId
                       withTenant:(NSString *)tenant
{
    [self.authContext.tokenCacheStore removeAllWithError:nil];

    NSURLSession *urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]
                                                             delegate: nil
                                                        delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://login.windows.net/%@/oauth2/logout", tenant]];
    [[urlSession dataTaskWithURL:url
               completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
               {
               }] resume];
}
```