# ADAL tokens not revoking on logout

Tags: angularjs, adal, adal.js

Im able to login to my angularjs app using the [angular adal library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js)
I can get a token and verify this token. My question is the following:

If i signout, should the token get revoked automatically? If not, how do i do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Azure Active Directory does not support or provide an endpoint for an application to revoke the access/refresh tokens.

You may read more about [configurable token lifetimes in Azure Active Director](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes)y to check the policies on token lifetimes and adjust that base on your requirement .

There is a sample logout code that you may be able to integrate as a workaround. 
See: [Can Azure AD ADAL (ios) refresh token be revoked from the client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405094/can-azure-ad-adal-ios-refresh-token-be-revoked-from-the-client)