# Microsoft ADAL Signout

Tags: ios, swift, access-token, adfs, adal

I am using Microsoft ADAL library in one of my project. I am using the library method **acquireTokenWithResource:clientId:redirectUri:completionBlock**: for the sign in purpose, and upon sign out I am just clearing the token cache and all the other cookies.Everything is working as expected.But it seems like token is not getting expired upon sign out, as I've checked by using the same token in Postman.

So how I can inform Microsoft that user has signed out? 
Do I need to call any API upon sign out?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061948/adal-w8-1-app-trying-to-log-user-out) - It is for Windows, but it should be pretty straight-forward to implement on iOS.  There does not seem to be specific function in ADALiOS to make this call.

Comment: yeah me too thought the same.But I've just checked with postman calling some APIs for the same user.If token got expired after sign-out means it should throw 401 - Unauthorized error , but it didn't.And token is expiring only after 1 hour, no matter whether user has signed out or not.

Comment: Well, I guess in theory the token should be confidential, so if your app discards all copies then even though it is still valid, it can't be used (since no one knows it).

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime of the access_token is independent of the login session of a user who grants access to a client.So even user logout ,access token still available in it's lifetime .

AFAIK, azure ad doesn't provide an effective way to revoke the access token, you could [config the appropriate lifetime of access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) to reduce risks. It has a relatively short validity (default is 1 hour) and as soon as it expires it must be refreshed with a refresh token.

Any feedback about Azure AD , you could post to [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory).